# Not being able to use 'from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryOperator' in Airflow 2.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am learning Cloud Composer and Airflow in Google Cloud Platform. I am trying to do some transformations and load into another table. `from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryOperator` gives me an error and i have looked through airflow documentation and cant see if it has been changed or not. This is my code

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryOperator

bq_to_bq  = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id                     = "bq_to_bq",
        sql                         = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `raw_bikesharing.stations`",
        destination_dataset_table   = 'dwh_bikesharing.temporary_stations_count',
        write_disposition           = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        create_disposition          = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        use_legacy_sql              = False,
        priority                    = 'BATCH'
 )
```

> No name 'BigQueryOperator' in module 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery'

Comment: I looked at the following page which lists the operators provided as part of the BigQuery package and none of them appear to be called `BigQueryOperator`.   If what you want to do is run a query, it looks like BigQueryInsertJobOperator is the operator you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is another up to date operator with `Airflow` to execute query and create a job : `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`

I think you didn’t used an existing one :

```py
import airflow

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

execute_query = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='execute_query_task_id',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "select …",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
        location='EU'
    )
```

You can check this example from my Github [repository](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-airflow-beam-bq/blob/main/team_league/dag/team_league_dag.py).